# MariaDB Select Distinct ON (An Expression was Expected (Near ON)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, distinct

I am trying to do a simple query using Distinct On a Column (As i still want to return all other columns in the table)
But when i attempt to use the ON (Column) clause it keeps displaying an error
"An Expression was expected (Near ON)"

I have no idea what this message means, as the query appears to be formatted correctly, is this something specific with MariaDB instead of MySQL?

MariaDB version 10.3.28   If this is of any use?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (No, Branch) *
FROM   Table1
ORDER  BY No, a DESC;
```

[image]

Table1

```
|    ID     |     No     |    Branch     |     Datetime     |

| --------- | ---------- | ------------- | ---------------- |

| 1         | 1          |  1            | 18/10/2021 10:00 |
| 2         | 1          |  1            | 19/10/2021 10:00 |
| 3         | 1          |  2            | 22/10/2021 10:00 |
| 4         | 1          |  2            | 20/10/2021 11:37 |
| 5         | 1          |  1            | 21/10/2021 10:00 |
| 6         | 1          |  1            | 22/10/2021 11:37 |
| 7         | 2          |  1            | 20/10/2021 10:00 |
| 8         | 2          |  1            | 22/10/2021 11:37 |
```

Basically i was wanting to use Distinct on "No" and "Branch" to essentially give me 1 record where No and Branch are unique and its using the MAX(Datetime)

I have attempted to use Group by clause, but this gives me a row with mixed results from other rows.

The results i am after would be:

```
|    ID     |     No     |    Branch     |     Datetime     | 
| --------- | ---------- | ------------- | ---------------- |
| 6         | 1          |  1            | 22/10/2021 11:37 |
| 3         | 1          |  2            | 22/10/2021 10:00 |
| 8         | 2          |  1            | 22/10/2021 11:37 |
```

I would be wanting to to display all columns in the table, as i will also be doing a Join to fetch the Name based on No and Branch

Comment: *Distinct On a Column* Not implemented.

Comment: *i was wanting to use Distinct on "No" and "Branch" to essentially give me 1 record where No and Branch are unique and its using the MAX(Datetime)* This is GROUP BY, not DISTINCT. In DISTINCT ON the columns not listed in an expression returns one indefinite value from all existing, not MAX.

Comment: I have used Group By, but i have 4 different Date fields, an i end up with a mix result showing Dates from different rows regardless of No 1 - row having its own dates, the results from a Group by return dates from a different row, am led to believe Group By clause is free to pick any of the matching rows is each group, meaning my row wont be same as what is in the DB.

Comment: I can see i will just have to do a pre-query to accomplish what i want, I just thought with some of the basic functions like Distinct etc, this would of been possible in a much cleaner method

Comment: *I have used Group By* Add this attempt into the question. Have you used MAX() function in it?

Comment: Yes, i was using the Max(Date) in the select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE table_tst (
  `ID` int(5),
  `No` int(5), 
  `Branch` int(5), 
  `Datetime` Datetime
);
    
INSERT INTO table_tst VALUES 
(1,1,1,'2021-10-18 10:00:00'),
(2,1,1,'2021-10-19 10:00:00'),
(3,1,2,'2021-10-22 10:00:00'),
(4,1,2,'2021-10-20 11:37:00'),
(5,1,1,'2021-10-21 10:00:00'),
(6,1,1,'2021-10-22 11:37:00'),
(7,2,1,'2021-10-20 10:00:00'),
(8,2,1,'2021-10-22 11:37:00');


   select * 
from table_tst where (No,Branch,Datetime) in 
(
select `No`,`Branch`,MAX(`Datetime`)  as max_time
from table_tst
group by `No`,`Branch`
)
order by No ,Branch ASC;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhqJXYFy52xRtVBc97R1EL/8

`datetime` is a reserved word in `mysql` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html and it should be in backticks or I suggest using other non reserved words

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked, added in a Join and some additional columns and works like a charm, I also learnt that Datetime is reserved amongst timestamp, i have renamed my table columns to avoid conflict Thank you.

Comment: @DaveHamilton I'm glad it helped